# Java Calling a method of super Class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a Class

```
public class GridColor 
{
    double min;
    double max;

    public GridColor(double min, double max) 
    {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public double getColorValue(double value)
    {
        return 15*value*min/max;
    }
}
```

I have another class

```
public class GridNewValue extends GridColor
{
    public GridNewValue(double min, max)
    {
        super(min, max);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double value = 0.5;
        GridNewValue gnv = new GridNewValue(0.0, 1.0);
        System.out.println(gnv.getColorValue(value));
    }

}
```

I am pretty new to Java. Basically I want to print the `value` returned by the method of super's `getColorValue(value)`. I know something is terribly wrong in my approach.
Please help me proceed

Comment: what are you expecting? Isn't it calling super's `getColorValue(value)` method?

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong; this should work and do basically what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is just fine :)

You created class and you inherit from her, And use one of her methods..

Of course, if you don't have anything to add to GridNewValue so you don't need the override but this is ok

Answer (score 1):

If you don't override `getColorValue()`, the super class's implementation will be called anyway. Therefore, you're on the right track already.

There's just one small syntax error:

```
public GridNewValue(double min, max)
```

should be

```
public GridNewValue(double min, double max)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not override the method in your subclass, calling the method with a subclass instance will automatically call the superclass definition.
Basically, you are already doing what you want your code to do.

Answer (score 0):

In java the subclass - in your case `GridNewValue` automatically has the same properties as its parent class. So unless you override `getColorValue()` in the `GridNewValue` class, when calling `(new GridNewValue()).getColorValue()` it will call the method in the parent.